# Graphenedb Triggers Issue (https://app.graphenedb.com/)

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc, graphenedb

I m new to the Neo4j platform. Our team is working to migrate from SQL to Graph. We were able to enable APOC triggers when we were in working local environment but when we deployed it to Graphenedb instance we were not able to find any configuration or remote shell access to configure APOC triggers. I contacted their support, but there is no reply. We are in a kind of pickle here, so it would be a huge help to us if someone can provide any solution. We just want to write a single configuration line in the setting which would enable the trigger

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation it looks like you can enable APOC using these steps: https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/stored-procedures#section-adding-apoc

Comment: Thanks for the reply , Yes I have already seen this, it says how to add the APOC stored procedure. But APOC does not enable triggers by default ,we have to enable it  by  using config file which I can't find anywhere in the dashboard.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, I missed that detail in your question